# discord.js username not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

for reasons, I am trying to get the username using the user's ID, and so, I have tried many things but they all result in `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` this is what I have:

```
user = bot.users.cache.find(user => user.id === key); //key is the user's id

console.log(user);
bot.channels.cache.get("847470926748057671").send(user.username); //this is where the error is
```

and where it outputs user to the log, it says

```
User {
  id: '691615336943845407',
  system: false,
  locale: null,
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 128 },
  username: 'orangenal name',
  bot: false,
  discriminator: '7363',
  avatar: 'e99b5e3d3edcfa7e22dd76a7eb869c62',
  lastMessageID: '847498366236885053',
  lastMessageChannelID: '847470926748057671'
}
```

so there is a username, but I do not know how to access it

Comment: I think you have to put `await` before `bot.users.cache.find(user => user.id === key)` and await the bot to finish searching for the user

Comment: No, await is only for users.fetch()

Comment: Besides, if it was a promise, it would say `Promise<Pending>` in the console since there is no await

Comment: You are trying to access it the correct way, however, I will give you this tip: instead of using `.find()`, if you have the user ID, just do `<bot>.users.cache.get(key)` which will get the user by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fetch()` and make sure to handle the promise

```
bot.users.fetch(key)
   .then(res => user = res)
   .catch(console.error);
console.assert(!user, 'User was not found!');


const channel = bot.channels.cache.get("847470926748057671");
channel.send(user?.username);
```